# Magento 2: Override js in custom module doesn't work?

Tags: magento2, javascript, overrides

I'm trying to override js in custom module, but that module which i want to override is already override some js from magento_checkout.

And seem like it doesn't work :(

Here is how i did:
[image]

That module is override from magento_checkout:
[image]

Alright, so i did this before and its work, but for some reason, i fixed it, and now it doesn't work anymore, and i can't find the way to fix this back to work :(
EDIT 1:

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Amasty\Deliverydate\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" type="Gssi\Deliverydate\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor"/>

    <!-- TAIG-8 #2: add "PO #" field in "BuyersOrderNumber" -->
    <preference for="Amasty\Deliverydate\Plugin\Checkout\ShippingInformationManagement" type="Gssi\Deliverydate\Plugin\Checkout\ShippingInformationManagement"/>
</config>
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: my di.xml file doesn't using anything to do with this, but if you want, i will update it so you can see it closer :)
please stand by

Answer (score 0):

Update your `module.xml` file at `Gssi/Deliverydate/etc/module.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http7://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Gssi_Deliverydate" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Amasty_Deliverydate"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Hope, It may be helpful for you.

Comment: Doesn't work, it still call to Amasty_Deliverydate/js/shipping-save-processor/default-override

Comment: Yes. It will call that js file.

Comment: so what i want is call to my js file, not that js file :(

Comment: You need to call that js file as like call in Amasty extension & need to maintain sequence. If first your module call then you need to add that above code in amasty extension.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you said, can you tell more detail on this? Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Hope you doing well.

Please go through this link of Magento DevDocs.

**Replace a default JS component**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

**Create a RequireJS configuration file requirejs-config.js, having specified the following:**

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "<default_component>": "<custom_component>"
    }
  }
};
```

**For example, if you want to use custom navigation-menu.js script instead of the default menu widgets, your requirejs-config.js should contain the following:**

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "menu": "js/navigation-menu",
      "mage/backend/menu": "js/navigation-menu"
    }
  }
};
```

Hope this will help you.

Please try this one also, this is worked for me.

```
var config = {
    config: {
            mixins: {
                'vendor_module/js/filename': {
                    'vendor_module/js/filename-mixin': true
                },
            }
        },
    }
```

Comment: Yes i've follow this instruction from the beginning, but unfortunately it doesn't work for my sitution :(

Comment: please try this one i have update the answer, i have tried this and this one works for me.